# how to trigger change function forcefully

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery function which sends an AJAX request and receives a response accurately.

```
  $('#region_id').on('change', function() {
     //some AJAX request and response which works great.
  });
```

`region_id` is a `select` tag and has a couple of region names.

When I select a region name from this drop down list, it leads to load another drop down list named `city_id`. But for some reasons, when I load this page I need to call `region_id` change function which automatically loads the city drop down list.

`change` event actually works when drop down item selection changed but I need to call this change function so that during page load, my city drop down also loaded.

I have tried this:

```
$('#region_id').trigger('change'); //Forcefully call a function
```

Comment: isnt that working? http://jsfiddle.net/KWcVr/1/

Comment: It should be working...

Comment: If your current code doesn't work, post all (or at least more) of your HTML/JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might help you:

```
$('#region_id').on('change', function() {
     alert('Test alert');
  });
$('#region_id').val(' ').trigger('change'); // set value as you want to change
```

Answer (score 0):

Its work perfect .

html:

```
<input type="text"  id="region_id">
```

jquery:

```
 $('#region_id').on('change', function() {
     alert('Test alert');
  });
$('#region_id').trigger('change');
```

Sample fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/Y2Cbv/)